# Maven Hibernate dependencies

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

In my project I have the following dependencies:

```
hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.ga.jar
|
|----hibernate-3.2.1.ga.jar
```

As far as I can see, the `hibernate-3.2.1.ga.jar` and `hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar` contains pretty much the same classes. Now, during the debugging session I've noticed that there are two `org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl` classes. One is from the `hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar` and one is from the `hibernate-3.2.1.ga.jar`. When I call the `uniqueResult` method on a `Criteria` object, the `uniqueResult` which is from the `hibernate-3.2.1.ga.jar`'s `CriteriaImpl` is applied.

That's not a behavior I want. How can I manage the dependencies so that the `CriteriaImpl` from `hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar` is applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular dependency is coming directly from [hibernate-commons-annotations' POM file](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-commons-annotations/3.3.0.ga/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.ga.pom).

It is likely the case that you've got a project which is picking this up as a dependency, so what you want to do is [explicitly exclude it](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) as something that could be picked up for other classes to use.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0-ga</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Not just exclude. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.cglib.proxy.CallbackFilter

Comment: Make sure that you've got the other parts declared as explicit dependencies in your POM.  You don't show us what that looks like so I'm only taking a guess here.  Further, be sure that `mvn depdendency:resolve` completes successfully, and that you are certain that you're still getting that issue on a rebuild of your project.